# Turn UIPageViewController page in combination with AVCaptureSession

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, avcapturesession

I have the following setup:

A UIPageviewController that has two child-ViewControllers.
ViewController 1 contains a UITableView, ViewController 2 holds a camera setup (AVCaptureSession, etc). It's basically a Snapchat like setup.

Swiping between the two works perfectly - swipe left, UITableView is showing, swipe right and the camera shows up again. So far so good.

Now I want to implement a button that turns the page to get to the controller that hold the UITableView programatically. Here's how I do it:

```
let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [startingViewController!]
pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works for the most part, as it slides out the UIViewController holding the camera instance and slides in the one holding the UITableView. However, it seems like the view controller that holds the camera session is deallocated, so when I swipe right again, the camera has to be fired up again. Is there any way to turn the page differently, without having the camera session deallocated?

I have tried adding the camera to the PageViewcontroller and adding an "invisible" overlay, but this is not the solution I am looking for. Can someone help out here?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is using a UIScrollView with multiple subviews and paging enabled. When you press the button, you do not "turn the page", you manipulate/animate the content of the scroll view.

For further reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html